# Oracle Order By different columns same select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have an interesting problem here. But it is just for knowledge because I already solve it in a non elegant way.

I have a table that have costumers and they can be holders or dependants and this relation is described as a 
family. Each family can have only a holder and 0-n dependants. A holder is identified by an H and a Dependant by a D.

What I need is a way to order the data by name of holder and theirs dependants. So the sample data below

```
idcostumer      name                 idfamily        relation
    1         Natalie Portman           1               H
    2         Mark Twain                3               D
    3         Carl Sagan                2               D
    4         Bob Burnquist             2               H
    5         Sheldon Cooper            1               D
    6         Anakin Skywalker          4               H
    7         Luke Skywalker            4               D
    8         Leia Skywalker            4               D
    9         Burnquist Jr.             2               D
    10        Micheal Jackson           3               H
    11        Sharon Stone              1               H
    12        Michelle Pfeiffer         3               D
```

Is it possible to get the above results in just one query? As you can see the order is name (just for the holders)

```
idcostumer      name                 idfamily        relation
    6         Anakin Skywalker          4               H
    8         Leia Skywalker            4               D
    7         Luke Skywalker            4               D
    4         Bob Burnquist             2               H
    9         Burnquist Jr.             2               D
    3         Carl Sagan                2               D
    10        Micheal Jackson           3               H
    2         Mark Twain                3               D
    12        Michelle Pfeiffer         3               D
    11        Sharon Stone              1               H
    1         Natalie Portman           1               D
    5         Sheldon Cooper            1               D
```

The test case data for this example.

```
create table costumer (
    idcostumer integer primary key,
    name varchar2(20),
    idfamily integer,
    relation varchar2(1)
);
```

This is the inserts statments for this table:

```
insert into costumer values ( 1 , 'Natalie Portman'  , 1, 'D');
insert into costumer values ( 2 , 'Mark Twain'       , 3, 'D');
insert into costumer values ( 3 , 'Carl Sagan'       , 2, 'D');
insert into costumer values ( 4 , 'Bob Burnquist'    , 2, 'H');
insert into costumer values ( 5 , 'Sheldon Cooper'   , 1, 'D');
insert into costumer values ( 6 , 'Anakin Skywalker' , 4, 'H');
insert into costumer values ( 7 , 'Luke Skywalker'   , 4, 'D');
insert into costumer values ( 8 , 'Leia Skywalker'   , 4, 'D');
insert into costumer values ( 9 , 'Burnquist Jr.'    , 2, 'D');
insert into costumer values ( 10, 'Micheal Jackson'  , 3, 'H');
insert into costumer values ( 11, 'Sharon Stone'     , 1, 'H');
insert into costumer values ( 12, 'Michelle Pfeiffer', 3, 'D');
```

I've tried some things, create a father sun relationship with connect by statement and familyid concatenated with the relation.
Used a row_count with a over clause ordering by relation desc and family id, but this way I lost the name order.

Comment: Your insert statements does not tally with the expected output. In the insert statements `Sharon Stone` is a `D`, whereas in the expected output it is an `H`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to first order the families by the name of the holder, then by the names of the dependents.  The following does that.

```
with family_order as (
  select  idfamily, rownum r from (
    select idfamily from costumer where relation = 'H' order by name
  ) 
)
select c.* from costumer c 
inner join family_order fo on c.idfamily = fo.idfamily
order by fo.r, relation desc, name
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9714/6)

Comment: Sorry didn't work... Michael jackson appers in wrong place. He is the holder, so must be before Mark Twain which is his dependant

Comment: I Missed 1 sorting order - fixed

Comment: Yeah... now is alright. So, back to the question I posted before in the comment I deleted. Would it be performatic for a costumer table which have 500k+ rows and joining with some as big tables?

Comment: I don't think it would be too bad.  It would require two passes through the costumer table, so maybe not ideal.  A more performant version might be possible using some of oracle's analytic functions, but it would take me a bit to figure out how.

Comment: I will search for theese analytics functions to learn about it, as I'm not familiarized with. Thanks anyway.

Comment: turns out that I already knew theese analytics functions but not with this name. :)

Comment: There is a minor problem with your solution. Suppose you have a family [Burns-holder, brian-dep, charles-dep] and another one [Carl-holder, Alysson-dep, Zack-dep] In your query the family of Carl will appear first in the result because the `order by min(name)` will get 'Alysson-dep' so to solve this you have to add `where relation='H'` so they will get only the name of the holders to order.

Comment: +1 Nice use of `with`! why didn't I think about it :)

Comment: You're right Jorge.  Don't even need the min() actually.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select * from table order by idfamily desc, relation desc, name asc
```

Link to **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/790ed/1)**

For un-natural order you can use "union all":

```
select * from (select idcostumer, name, idfamily, relation from costumer 
  where idfamily > 3
  order by idfamily desc, relation desc, name asc)
union all
select * from (
  select idcostumer, name, idfamily, relation from costumer 
  where idfamily = 2
  order by idfamily desc, relation desc, name asc)
union all
select * from (
  select idcostumer, name, idfamily, relation from costumer 
  where idfamily != 2 and idfamily < 4
  order by idfamily desc, relation desc, name asc)
```

Link to **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b7ab/1)**

Comment: in this way you don't order the holder costumers by name first

Comment: as you can see in the sample example the family ids is 4, 2, 3 and 1

Comment: I think you didn't undestand the problem this way you answer is way to easy... use the statments and try your query, you will see that the result is not what is needed

Comment: I've corrected a insert statment, sheldon is familyid 1. and in your answer Michel jackson appears in the 5th when should be 7th

Comment: @JorgeCampos did you check out the link to the Fiddle I posted ?

Comment: Yeah. Did you compare your answer with the desired result?

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Just because the answer to a problem seems too simple doesn't mean it is not right.

Comment: @alfasin: Your fiddle's insert statements set `Sheldon Cooper` to family `4` instead of `1`

Comment: @JorgeCampos if you want to order by family ids which are not in natural order (asc/desc) - you *will* have to work harder. For example, run this query 3 times (one for values >2, once of familyid=2, and one for lowers) and `union` the results.

Comment: @beny23 you're looking at an older link (before the OP changed the inserts) - re-click the link and you'll see the newer version with the correct id.

Comment: Sorry guys I made some mistakes with the data! I Already corrected it.  @beny23 I said it because I have some oracle background experience and you guys didn't undertand the problem. If the answer was just that I would have asked this question.

Comment: @alfasin Yeah, I tried it with some subqueries and even with the WITH clause selecting just the holders then left joining with everithing generating some IDs ordered by OVER clause

Comment: @JorgeCampos updated my answer, you can also see [*fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b7ab/1)

Comment: @alfasin This is an especific example of data, in a final query I could not fix the ids in unions like "idfamily != 2". But thanks for your effort. As I said in the question is just for knowledge. The real problem involves tables with more than 500k rows with lots of joins with other tables.